# How to implement a switch button with a button

Tags: android

Helllo, i'm new in programming android my question is there a method for let a button create a new switch button with some caratteristic i want to, for example the name and a number.

Answer (score 2):

its not so clear what you want
but i made an app that has a button
when clicking the button, it is adding a switch to the view
(but i didnt understand what you ment with name and number)

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //adding the switch button
            Switch addedSwitch = new Switch(getBaseContext());
            LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            linearLayout.addView(addedSwitch, layoutParams);
        }});
}}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.recntrek7.stack.MainActivity">
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="press"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp" /></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes sorry i wasn't so much clear. I meant that when you press that button open you another windows where you can set a text bethween switch and i wanted to add a number to the switch. Hope i was clear this time